# Physical disks comprising a Volume in RHEL

Tags: redhat, storage, lvm, hard-drive

How do I list the physical disks and associated information (disk model, size, etc.) for all disks that are members of a physical volume in RHEL?

For example, if I do I "pvscan", I get the following information:

```
  PV /dev/sdc1   VG VolGroup02   lvm2 [2.60 TB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sdb1   VG VolGroup01   lvm2 [2.60 TB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sda2   VG VolGroup00   lvm2 [1.23 TB / 0    free]
```

How do I find out how many and what kind of disks make up the volumes?  I am basically trying to determine the speed of the disks (e.g. 7200 RPM, 10000 RPM, etc)  I figure I can determine that if I can get the disk models of the disks in each volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install sg3_utils for some useful scsi tools:

sginfo:

```
#  sginfo /dev/sdb


INQUIRY response (cmd: 0x12)
----------------------------
Device Type                        0
Vendor:                    VMware,
Product:                   VMware Virtual S
Revision level:            1.0
Device Capacity:


# sg_readcap /dev/sdb

    Read Capacity results:
      Last logical block address=208895 (0x32fff), Number of blocks=208896
      Logical block length=512 bytes
    Hence:
      Device size: 106954752 bytes, 102.0 MiB, 0.11 GB
```

There are many of these sg commands to investigate. See RedHat Article ID: 17988 Understanding SCSI addressing on RedHat Enterprise Linux

Comment: Where would I get sginfo/sg3_utils?  It is not installed on my system.  Is sg3_utils the package name?

Comment: @GregH : a) from the repos, b) yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can pull data about your disks by looking at `hdparm`

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda
hdparm -I /dev/sdb
hdparm -I /dev/sdc
```

Those will work if it's not a part of a hardware raid.. if it is you have to look at `dmesg` output and the vendor-specific raid controller tools suchs as tw_cli (3ware) or hpacucli (HP).

Comment: Sorry,I should have included that "hdparm" does not work on my system.  When I issue that command I get:  "HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid argument"

Comment: then it's behind some kind of raid controller like I mentioned. So you need to look at `dmesg`